# Ito differential of expectation with respect to a measure

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

How could one think of taking the Ito differntial of an expectation or measure theortic integral?

In particular, I know how an Ito process $D_t$ evolves ($dD_t = \mu dt + \sigma dW_t$) and that it equals an expectation of some variable, $x$, at time $t$.  I would like to take the Ito differential and equate coefficients.

So, how could one think about this ito differential:

$
d\mathbb{E}^{G_t}[x] = d\left(\int x dG_t(x) \right)
$

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is right! If anyone happens along later, please let me know if I'm on the right track.

References:

Da Prato, et. al., "Stochastic Equations in Infinite Dimensions"
Carmona, et. al., "Interest Rate Models: an Infinite Dimensional Stochastic Analysis Perspective"

The above expression can be rewritten (assuming $G_t(x)$ admits a density) as
$$
\begin{align*}
d\mathbb{E}^{G_t}[x] &= d\left(\int x dG_t(x) \right) \\
&= d\left(\int x g_t(x)d(x) \right) \\
&= dF(g_t)\\
\end{align*}
\\
$$
where $F(g_t)$ is a functional from the space of probability measures to $\mathbb{R}$.

Suppose that the dynamics of the stochastic distribution $g_t(x)$ are known, such that
$$
\begin{align*}
g_t(x) = g_0(x) + \int_0^t \phi_s(x)ds + \int_0^t \Phi_s(x) dW_s(x)
\end{align*}
$$

The following definition of an Ito's lemma on such functionals can be used to calculate the differential (see theorem 4.32 from Da Prato. Also, I maintain their notation here because it is more concise.):
$$
\begin{align*}
F(t, X(t)) &= F(0, X(0)) + \int_0^t \langle F_x(s, X(s), \Phi(s)dW(s) \rangle +\\
&\int_0^t \left \lbrace F_t(s, X(s)) +  \langle F_x(s, X(s), \phi(s) + \frac{1}{2}\text{Tr}[F_{xx}(s, X(s))(\Phi(s)Q^{1/2})(\Phi(s)Q^{1/2})^*]\rangle \right \rbrace ds
\end{align*}
$$
What's left to do in my answer is define the derivative of $F(g_t)$, but this should simply be a functional derivative.